# How to format DayTime as Day of week Medium Time on Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, format, sqldatatypes

I was trying some SQL out on Access, but when I am trying to format the `Date/Time` data type so that I can input the day of the week and the medium time for my variables.

For example, I want to be able to input something like: `Mon 1:00 PM`.

I have tried formatting the data type as `ddd h:nn AM/PM`, but when I am trying to input the value, the system gives me an error stating that the input does not match my format.

I have also tried to auto-fill the input by clicking on the calendar next to the input box and selecting a date, but this way I cannot format the time.

Any help would be appreciated.

I did not add any pictures or code because I do not think that is needed to answer the question. If anything extra is needed, I am more than willing to provide them.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can't enter the date/time in the formatted layout/text.

Although the date/time value is displayed according to your 'Format' property, it changes as soon as you move the cursor into the field or click into it.

Then you have to enter it in the conventional way, i.e. date and if desired the time behind it.

With the calendar you can only enter the date, unfortunately no the time. You would have to enter the time in the field yourself after you have selected the date.

The only way I see to enter date/time formatted is to write a VBA routine that interprets your input and puts the correctly formatted conventional text into your textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a form bound to the table holding two *unbound* controls to display and modify the weekday and time - like this mock-up:

[image: Mock up]

The two textboxes at top are *bound* to the Id and the date/time field of the table/query.

When opening the form, the combobox will be filled with the days of the week, and the first date of the week is calculated.

At the *OnCurrent* event, the combobox will be set to the weekday, and the textbox to the time. Modifying either of these will update the current record.

The combobox must be set to use a *ValueList* as *RowSource* and have the first column hidden (set *ColumnWidths* to: **0;**)

The Time textbox can have the *Format*: Short time format

The code of the form will be:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private FirstDate       As Date
Private FirstWeekDay    As VbDayOfWeek

Private Sub Form_Current()

    Me!Weekday.Value = DatePart("w", Me!Date.Value)
    Me!Time.Value = TimeValue(Me!Date.Value)

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim DayOfWeek       As VbDayOfWeek
    Dim LastWeekDay     As VbDayOfWeek
    Dim RowSource       As String

    FirstDate = DateAdd("d", Date, 1 - DatePart("w", Date, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek))
    FirstWeekDay = DatePart("w", FirstDate, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek)

    For DayOfWeek = 1 To 7
        RowSource = RowSource & """" & (FirstWeekDay - 1 + DayOfWeek) Mod 7 + 1 & """;""" & Format(DateAdd("d", DayOfWeek - 1, FirstDate), "dddd") & """;"
    Next
    Debug.Print RowSource
    Me!Weekday.RowSource = RowSource

End Sub

Private Sub Time_AfterUpdate()

    UpdateDate

End Sub

Private Sub Weekday_AfterUpdate()

    UpdateDate

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateDate()

    Me!Date.Value = DateAdd("d", (Me!Weekday.Value - 1 - FirstWeekDay + 7) Mod 7, FirstDate) + Nz(Me!Time.Value, #12:00:00 AM#)

End Sub
```